# Client unable to verify SSL certificate even when verification is disabled

Tags: ssl, certificate, verification

I am disabling certificate verification using the following command:

`getsessionkey = requests.post(AUTH_URL, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)`

I use above command in a script that calls an API to retrieve data from it. When I run my script, I have the following error:

`SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)`

I understand from that error that the script could not verify the distant's API certificate. But I am explicitely disabling the verification, I am at loss as to how to interpret this.

If the problem cannot be resolved, how can I add my certificate to the certificate truststore?

P.S: Disabling certificate verification has always worked for me so far. I started to have the error above since a recent security update.

Thanks for helping.